# How to resolve typescript error while using model id as a string variable in Strapi backend?

Tags: typescript, strapi

I'm trying to use string variable as a model id:

```
const model = {
  uid: "api::page.page"
};
const mainEntry = await strapi.entityService.findOne(model.uid, id, {
  fields: ["title"],
});
```

but I get a typescript error: `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ContentType'.` Any suggestion?

[image]

I have tried to generate types and they seems to be generated correctly.